# Convert Sum(case) SQL statement to LINQ query in Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, linq

Below is my SQL query that I'm looking to convert to LINQ query

```
SELECT 
    ProcessName,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'In-Progress' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As 'In-Progress',
    SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'Success' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As 'Completed',
    Count(CASE WHEN status in ('In-Progress','Success') then 1 end) as Total
FROM
    TableName
GROUP BY 
    ProcessName
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part is easy. The SQL expression `SUM(CASE WHEN condition THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` directly maps to the LINQ `Sum(condition ? 1 : 0)`.

More interesting is the SQL expression `COUNT(CASE WHEN condition THEN 1 END`. It's a shortcut for `COUNT(CASE WHEN condition THEN 1 ELSE NULL END`. Now, taking into account that SQL `COUNT` function skips the NULL values, the LINQ mapping could be either `Count(condition)` or `Sum(condition ? 1 : 0)`. From my experience with EF, the later translates to a better SQL (the former generates additional subquery reading from the source table), so I always prefer it in LINQ to Entities queries.

With that being said, the LINQ query could be something like this:

```
// constants to avoid typos
const string StatusInProgress = "In-Progress";
const string StatusCompleted = "Success";
// needed for IN clause 
var statuses = new[] { StatusInProgress, StatusCompleted };
// the query
var query =
    from e in db.TableA
    group e by e.ProcessName into g
    select new
    {
        InProgress = g.Sum(e => e.Status == StatusInProgress ? 1 : 0),
        Completed = g.Sum(e => e.Status == StatusCompleted ? 1 : 0),
        C = g.Sum(e => statuses.Contains(e.Status) ? 1 : 0),
    };
```

and the generated SQL looks like this:

```
SELECT
    1 AS [C1],
    [GroupBy1].[K1] AS [ProcessName],
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C2],
    [GroupBy1].[A2] AS [C3],
    [GroupBy1].[A3] AS [C4]
    FROM ( SELECT
        [Extent1].[K1] AS [K1],
        SUM([Extent1].[A1]) AS [A1],
        SUM([Extent1].[A2]) AS [A2],
        SUM([Extent1].[A3]) AS [A3]
        FROM ( SELECT
            [Extent1].[ProcessName] AS [K1],
            CASE WHEN (N'In-Progress' = [Extent1].[Status]) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [A1],
            CASE WHEN (N'Success' = [Extent1].[Status]) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [A2],
            CASE WHEN ([Extent1].[Status] IN (N'In-Progress', N'Success')) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [A3]
            FROM [dbo].[TableName] AS [Extent1]
        )  AS [Extent1]
        GROUP BY [K1]
    )  AS [GroupBy1]
```

As you can see, except the ugly outer parts that do nothing, the main part contained in the innermost subquery is almost identical to the SQL query in question.

Answer (score 1):

You may do something like that :

```
   var statuses = new {"In-Progress","Success"};


var res = yourData
          .GroupBy(m => m.ProcessName)
          .Select(g => new {
             ProcessName = g.Key,

             //for InProgress, 2 (or 3) ways
             InProgress = g.Select(x => x.Status == "In-Progress" ? 1 : 0).Sum(),
             //another way
             InProgress = g.Where(x => x.Status == "In-Progress").Count(),
             //another way, not sure if it works in linq to entities
             InProgress = g.Count(x => x.Status == "In-Progress"),

             //same 3 ways possible for completed, the first here
             Completed = g.Select(x => x.status == "Success" ? 1 : 0).Sum(),

             //for the count
             //not sure if this one works in linq to entities
             Total = g.Count(x => statuses.Contains(x.Status))
             //alternative
             Total = g.Where(x => statuses.Contains(x.Status)).Count()
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 string statuses = new {"In-Progress","Success"};

var results = from item in TableName
              group item by p.ProcessName into g
              select new yourReturnType 
              { 
                 ProcessName = g.Key,
                 In-Progress = g.Where(l=>l.Status == "In-Progress").Count(),
                 Completed = g.Where(l=>l.Status == "Success").Count(),                     
                 Total = g.Where(x => statuses.Contains(x.Status)).Count()

              };
```