# Entity Framework Core count with expression parameter

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework-core, expression

I am trying to use Entity Framework Core to generate a performant server-side SQL query, that counts records in a few groups. For example, let's say I have the table:

```
CREATE TABLE ExOrders
(
    Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    Column1 VARCHAR(250),
    Column2 INT,
    ColumnN VARCHAR(500),
)
```

and the result should be the select query:

```
select 
    count(<count1Condition>) as C1,
    count(<count2Condition>) as C2
from 
    ExOrders
where 
    <whereGenericCondition>
```

For each condition I have an `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` expression already generated.

What I tried so far

1. The Linq `Count()` function

   I am trying to get the above result with a query like:

```
Expression<Func<T, bool>> whereGenericCondition = GetExpression1();
Expression<Func<T, bool>> count1Condition = GetExpression2();
Expression<Func<T, bool>> count2Condition = GetExpression3();

var countRequestS1 = _dbcontext.Set<T>()
    .Where(whereGenericCondition)
    .GroupBy(s => 0)
    .Select(agg => new
                   {
                       C1 = agg.Count(count1Condition), // <- parameter error
                       C2 = agg.Count(count2Condition)  // <- parameter error
                   });
```

The problem is the `Count` extension doesn't support expression parameters.

Error:

> Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<T, bool>>' to 'System.Func<T, bool>'

2. The Linq `Count()` function with `AsQueryable()`

   I tried to call `AsQueryable` before the `Count` method:

```
var countRequestS2 = _dbcontext.Set<T>()
    .Where(whereGenericCondition)
    .GroupBy(s => 0) // <- from this point onward it is executed clientside
    .Select(agg => new
    {
        C1 = agg.AsQueryable().Count(count1Condition), 
        C2 = agg.AsQueryable().Count(count2Condition) 
    });
```

But in this case it just gets all the data into the app, and processes it locally (unaceptable scenario in my case, because there are hundreds of thousands of lines).

3. Pre-compiling the expressions

I have also tried compiling `count1Condition` and `count2Condition` expressions before using them:

```
var countRequestS3 = _dbcontext.Set<T>()
    .Where(whereGenericCondition)
    .GroupBy(s => 0) // <- from this point onward it is executed clientside
    .Select(agg => new
    {
        C1 = agg.Count(x => count1Condition.Compile()(x)),
        C2 = agg.Count(x => count2Condition.Compile()(x))
    });
```

But in this case it just gets all the data into the app, same as #2.

4. Implementing my own `Count()`

My last attempt was to implement my own `CountAfterGroupByMethod` but I get an error related to generic T type functions. 
In context model builder this crashes:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.HasDbFunction(typeof(CountAfterGroupByExtensions).GetMethod("CountAfterGroupBy"), options =>
    {
        options.HasTranslation(CountAfterGroupByExpressionTranslator.Translate);
    });
    // where CountAfterGroupBy is 
    // public static int CountAfterGroupBy<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate)
}
```

with error:

> System.ArgumentException: 'The DbFunction 'CountAfterGroupByExtensions.CountAfterGroupBy' is generic. Generic methods are not supported.'

Is there a flaw in #3 or #4 that I can't see? Or is there anything else I can try?

Comment: What is the sql you expect it to return here? normally in sql if you count two columns (which is what you seem to be doing) you'll get the same result twice unless you're trying to do a case statement of some kind. Here's another similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39590025/convert-sumcase-sql-statement-to-linq-query-in-entity-framework

Comment: Im pretty sure the LINQ translation doesn't support what you're trying to do. You'll probably have to run two separate queries and submit a feature proposal on the EF core GitHub page.

Comment: What is the exact EF Core version (unfortunately that matters)?

Answer (score 1):

A Count does not accept conditions, right. So put a

```
.Where(count1Condition).Count()
```

in front if your Count, and you have your conditional Count.

Comment: It appears as though the op is attempting to do two counts on separate criteria though, wouldn't this only support the one criteria?

Comment: No, its the right place, the right construct, everything is fine, you can do X.where(something).Count and X.where(somethingelse).Count together. At the end, the SQL-Provider is going to decide whether he can translate it to SQL, but most of them can.

Comment: But that's two separate queries rather than one query with two columns. The overhead of the round trips isn't efficient.

Comment: @KieranDevlin There is one semicolon at the end. It's one query. How do you get the idea it could be two ?

Comment: Because the method signature of count returns an int, how do you go from an integer back to a query?
`public static int Count<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source)`

Comment: @KieranDevlin C1 and C2 will be int. Nobody want to go 'back to a query'. The finaly result is a IQueryable<new {C1 int, C2 int}>.

Comment: You said "you can do X.where(something).Count and X.where(somethingelse).Count together", calling `Count()` forces the query to evaluate so how can you call count twice and not evaluate twice? Mind posting some code so we can see what you mean?

Comment: @KieranDevlin. No it doesn't. You are wrong. Count is a very basic SQL operation and will be translated into a query string. You mix up the little difference from Func<IQueryable,int> and Expression<Func<IQueryable, int>>. Inside a IQueryable you only have the Expression form. If the  expression cannot be translated to SQL, it will throw an exception, it will not 'execute' anything, cause it's not intended to do so.

Comment: @KieranDevlin The Code is there. Take the Version 1 from the OP without the count parameter and it will stay unexecuted nicely. It doesn't change if you insert a where clause either. You cannot be convinced from looking at code, you probably have to execute it. As long as you have only IQueryable functions on the outermost level, it's impossible to execute anything. Just technicly. It's send to the SQL-Provider. And it will make an SQL-Query out of it, or fail in doing so. There are no other Options. If you call Count() on the Outermost level, it will execute the query, but here we aren't.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I tried this too, and this is the same case as #1. Inside the Select() both Count and Where don't accept expressions as parameters, just lambdas. :(

Comment: @Razvan Why should a where work with Expression<Func<T, bool>> in Line 5 of your code `.Where(whereGenericCondition)` and not in like 9 ? That's impossible. Count has no parameters. Don't put any ! it's not Count(condition) its Where(condition).Count(). That's all.

Comment: @Holger Because on line 5 the object is a `IQueryable<T>` (with `Count` implementation from System.Linq.Queryable), and on line 9 it is an `IGrouping<int, T>` (with `Count` implementation from System.Linq.Enumerable). That's why in scenario #2, I tried to call the `AsQueryable()`.

Comment: @Razvan That is not important, inside a IQueryable everything is IQueryable or in other words, nothing is ever executed. It's completly OK to have the IEnumerable.Count cause it's not executed, its translated to SQL. I think your head is the only one telling you is has to be IQueryable - nobody else, not the compiler. You can also use some other functions like Math.Sqrt or List.Contains and they are never executed, they are just translated to SQL-strings.
Your "stick to IQueryable" is important for your outermost level. This is DbSet.Where().GroupBy().Select(); and that's completly fine.